# Use of *were* for routine action

Tags: meaning-in-context, present-tense, past-simple

Can we use simple present and past tense to tell routine everyday action?

> They are kept under surveillance.

Meaning they are kept under surveillance by their parents every day;

Or

It means they are just kept under surveillance for a day?

Or

Just reporting

Also

In reported speech if I say

> They were kept under surveillance

Has the same meaning as above but for a past situation, 
i.e. they were kept under surveillance by parents every day. Is that correct?

Comment: Regarding your question regarding reported speech, you might add an actual example to your question so is is easier to respond to..

Answer (score 1):

Yes!

One of the main functions of the simple present is indeed to show a habit (a routine everyday action) or something that is always true.

a) I make my own coffee (routine/habit)
b) I like oranges (always true)

The example "They are kept under surveillance" shows that this is a constant or habitual state.

If you wanted to show that the surveillance occurred only for a day, you would indicate that fact using either the exact time-frame and, if it is in the present time, the present continuous tense: "They are being kept under surveillance today/tomorrow/for a week"

Reported speech requires a speaker, so your example of "They were kept under surveillance" can not qualify. You could say:

"She said that they were kept under surveillance"

However, again, you would have to specify the exact time of the surveillance.

Answer (score 0):

*surveillance* would be considered a continuing action over some period of time. So I would not use simple present tense. The length of time around the present does not matter. So:

> They **are being** kept under surveillance.

When in the past, such continuing action would be thought to have ended, without additional context. So you can say:

> They **were** kept under surveillance.

I can't see where reported speech makes a difference.